# How to rename resources (images) in xCode using Swift code?

Tags: swift, bundle, file-rename

How do you loop through images in the bundle and rename them?

I have array of strings which are matching png files inside the App. (DAS, TRES, JY...etc -> DAS.png, TRES.png, JY.png...etc)

I am assuming, I should be able to use those to loop through all the matching files in the bundle. After, a match is made, I simply want to change name of that file to something else. (For example, I like to add "img_" to beginning of all matched .png files.)

Thank you

Comment: What's in the Bundle is not modifiable. Sort your files before adding them to the Bundle. // Or have your app copy them elsewhere outside the Bundle before modifying them.

Comment: @Moritz I got around 2000 files, I was looking for automated bulk-renaming option.

Comment: But this will happens only once, right? You're not going to rename the files every time the user starts the app I hope? I think @Moritz is right, do this first before adding the files to your project/bundle. Try to find some app that does this or write one yourself.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Only once I needed to do this. I will look for solution. Thank you.